# How to dynamically set style in a list item in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this menu in _Layout.cshtml :

```
<td class="MenuStructure">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("First Page", "Page1Action", "Main")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Second Page", "Page2Action", "Main")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Third Page", "Page3Action", "Second")</li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

When one of the action links is clicked, I want to set the class of the <li> which contains it to "selected" and the class of the other <li> elements to "".

This works :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var selMenu = '@ViewBag.SelectedMenu';
            if (selMenu == "page1") {
                $("#page1").attr('class', 'selected');
                $("#page2").attr('class', '');
                $("#page3").attr('class', '');
            }
            if (selMenu == "page2") {
                $("#page1").attr('class', '');
                $("#page2").attr('class', 'selected');
                $("#page3").attr('class', '');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

but it is awfully ugly.  Can someone show me a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a click event handler to the group of `a` elements, you can easily add the class to the clicked element's `li` and remove it for all siblings, regardless of how many there are. This removes the need for the if statements and the `attr` update for each `li`.

Here's a sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/JjBgm/4/

markup:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu li a').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });

});
```

You'd have to obviously modify this approach to your needs with MVC, but the concept should work.

**EDIT:** Because you mentioned there is a round-trip to the server involved the above may not work well. In that case you could construct the clientside id based on the selected menu and control the class from there.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selMenu = '@ViewBag.SelectedMenu';
    $("#" + selMenu).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

This is assuming `#page1`, `#page2`, etc. refer to the `<li>` elements without seeing your resulting markup after server processing.

If `#page1` refers to the `<a>` tag, then your statement would be:

```
$("#" + selMenu).parent().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
```

Untested of course. Main point is dynamically construct your selector, then use sibling and parent selectors as needed to clear the class. It's much cleaner.

Comment: The @Html.ActionLink within my li elements causes a postback (not sure if that is the right term in MVC3), so this works, but only for the brief moment before the page refreshes and no links have the "selected" class anymore.

Comment: @KennyZ ah yes didn't account for the round trip...I'll update

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is your main navigation for the site, and you want to keep the top menu "selected" even when you aren't on the exact action (eg, the link goes to list, but then you go to an 'edit' page, etc).

There are two ways to do it.  One is to put a property in the viewbag and then check that in the _layout.cshtml file when it is rendered.

```
// in controller Action method
ViewBag.SelectedMenu = "first"
// in view
<li class="@((ViewBag.SelectedMenu == "first") ? "selected-class" : "")">first link</li>
```

The second way (that we use) is to use the [Sitemap](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) package (install from NuGet).  Then you edit your Sitemap file in the root, and put all your links in there (even the ones that you don't use directly for navigation).  Then, you have the control render your `<ul><li>'s` for you.  It puts out the same html that you have right now, largely, so the css should still work.

- All menu stuff in one place
- Sitemap respects the [authorize] attribute, or other filters, hiding logged-in only links
- Can hide/show nodes in the menu that might not really exist (remapped urls, etc)
- Lots of other nice little features

`Mvc.sitemap` file:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Get a car" controller="Cars" action="Buy"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Reports" controller="Report" action="AllReports">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="" controller="Report" action="ViewMPG"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

And then, in your `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
<td class="MenuStructure">
    <!-- one level menu starting at top (home), including the "home" link -->
    @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(0, true, true, 1)
</td>
```

And then modify `Views\Shared\MenuHelperModel.cshtml` to change the style:

```
<ul id="menu">
    @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes)
    {
        var show = node.IsInCurrentPath && (!node.IsRootNode || node.IsCurrentNode);
        var cls = show ?  "selected" : ""; 
        <li class="@cls">@Html.DisplayFor(m => node)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Interesting.  But how does the Sitemap solution handle setting a class on the selected li node and removing it from the siblings?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot one part! Posted that quite late (for me) china time.  I'll added it.  Editing the template was just so standard it didn't even knock on my brain.  At least the idea of the ViewBag made it into the selected answer now, though.  In the end I think it's preferable to do it the sitemap way than to try to manually make sure that each action (and error, and post, etc) has the ViewBag property set.  I considered that way too, but thats a line of code in _every_ controller.